# Textbooks on cosmology *after* recombination

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, astronomy, stars

I am a theoretical physicist and I have a reasonable understanding of the early universe, inflation, FLRW metric, leptogenesis, baryogenesis, perturbations, the works (mainly in the style of the classic Kolb & Turner "The Early Universe"). However, I would like to improve my understanding of the evolution of the universe way ***after*** [recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_(cosmology)). Things I would like to have a better quantitative understanding of are

- What is the hierarchy of structures in the universe and how was it formed?
- Which types of galaxies can I encounter in which era and how do they fit within the point above?
- What is the mass of supermassive black holes as a function of redshift? What are the essential mechanisms of feedback between SMBHs and their host galaxies?
- How does metallicity in space evolve as a function of redshift? What is the timeline of the chemical evolution of the universe?
- Which stars can I encounter in which era? When are the first stellar remnants/ compact objects formed? How does binary star evolution fit into this? How do phenomena such as [pulsar recyclation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond_pulsar) fit into this timeline?
- How were cosmic magnetic fields formed?

In all of the points above I would also like to understand which observation and/or model leads to any answer.

I realize that some of these questions do not have known answers and that there may be no single book that would try to answer all of them. However, I would still be interested if there was a comprehensive "crash course for theorists" of two or three graduate-style textbooks that told me about the approximate state of the art.

Comment: Mo, van den Bosch, & White's "Galaxy Formation And Evolution" is only 10 years old, and covers many of these topics. You can find a .pdf version on the internet if you want to check it out before buying. I think it's a really good book.

Answer (score 1):

I did not read this book but I believe it will definitely suit you

Extragalactic Astronomy and Cosmology: An Introduction by Peter Schneider

Here is the first edition

[https://www.amazon.com/Extragalactic-Astronomy-Cosmology-Peter-Schneider/dp/3642069711](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642069711)

Here is the link for the second edition

[https://www.amazon.com/Extragalactic-Astronomy-Cosmology-Peter-Schneider/dp/3662500604](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3662500604)

Just go to the site and click "Look inside" to see the List of Contents. It nearly cover everything about the galaxy formation to stars etc.